# PHP implode function error, does not include implode string

Tags: php, laravel, implode

I'm using laravel 5.8 and am trying to get a foreach to implode

```php
foreach($stocks->currency as $currency)
{
  $d1 = $currency->cost;
  $d2 = $currency->currency->name;
  $currencies = array(' ' . $d1 . ' ' . $d2);
  echo implode("or", $currencies);
}
```

Is my code block

However, this returns the following :

[image]

clearly this lacks the "or" that the implode should add

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `array(' ' . $d1 . ' ' . $d2)` gives an array of 1 value (using `.` to concatenate the values).

Comment: @NigelRen yes, but I want the or to appear between each of the concatenated arrays, since $d1 is the cost integer and $d2 is the currency type. Would you happen to know how I can fix that issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like

```
$currencies = [] // Create an empty array
foreach($stocks->currency as $currency)
{
  $d1 = $currency->cost;
  $d2 = $currency->currency->name;
  $currencies[] = ' ' . $d1 . ' ' . $d2; // Add a new value to your array
}
echo implode("or", $currencies); // implode the full array and separate the values with "or"
```